# Python async grpc client stream handle

Tags: python, python-asyncio, grpc-python

I am a newbie to python async GRPC and I came up with this to handle an async stream:

```
async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel(target='localhost:6565', options=CHANNEL_OPTIONS) as channel:
            stub = get_results_grpc.ResultServiceStub(channel)
            stream = stub.GetResults(get_results_pb2.PositionsRequest(name=["test"]), timeout=10, metadata=metadata)
            try:
                async for resp in stream.__aiter__():
                    print(resp)
            except grpc.RpcError as e:
                print(e)

            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            stream.cancel()
```

However, once there is no result on in the steam, then loop will finish and then both the steam will be closed and the program exits. How could I keep the stream open ?

In Java, I could use a countdownLatch to keep async grpc stream open.

Comment: The timeout will expire 10s from when you initially make the call, regardless of data coming through or not. If you want to keep it open, then don't use a timeout.

Comment: @alkasm that's very helpful, thanks a lot.